# Side bar with Way points

Tags: html, css, jquery-waypoints

Hey my name is Kasper!

I'm making a side bar where on my portfolio website, I just learned about #Way points some day's ago.

And now I want to add that to my menu bar, But I can't seem to get it right, this is what my code looks like:

```
   <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper ----------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <div class="menu-links scroll-me">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                        <div href="#">
                            <a href="#header">
                                <img class="ImageFixsTyle" src="assets/img/logsmall.png" alt="SbnLogo" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <hr />
                    <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-archive fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <hr />
                    <li><a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-spin fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <hr />
                    <li><a href="#NewsLetter"><i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <hr />
                    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-mars-stroke fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <hr />
                    <li><a href="#contactme"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper ----------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

The Code can be seen in action on : http://kaslabdesign.dk/

now What I want to happen is each time I come to one of my Menu points The menu point we are at needs to be high Lighted.

I have looked at some guides but none of them have anything to do with my specific problem.
I hope anyone can help me to solve my problem since i'm soon bald because of this.

have a nice day/evening & thank you for reading this.
best regards Kasper.

p.s I hope someone can help me ;)! and I hope i explain good enought..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/
Handle each block as waypoint and when it is hit, highlight the associated link in the menu. The association is made by the **href** attribute.

```js
$(function() {
   $('p').waypoint({
       handler: function(direction) {
   $("a").css("color", "");
    $("a[href='#" + this.element.id + "']").css("color", "red");
  }
})
});
```

```css
ul {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#item1">item1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#item2">item2</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#item3">item3</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <p id="item1">a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br></p>
  <p id="item2">a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br></p>
  <p id="item3">a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your comment is very usefull, but it does not make me understand it fully, what would i exactly have to do to add the waypoint to each icon in my menubar? My backend is not very good sorry.

Comment: Link in your menu refers to and content within your page by the id of that content block. For instance you have block in your page with **id** attribute set to **clients** and than you have link in your sidebar with **href** attribute set to **#clients**. So you have to set waypoint for an element with id **clients** (which is your content) and when this waypoint is hit, you can highlight the corresponding link, just like I did in the exmaple.

Comment: This Li en the menu bar  <li><a href="#about">A<i class="fa fa-archive fa-2x"></i></a></li> and this is the first section : <section id="about"> but when to the section nothing happens I am using  $('p').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
   $("a").css("color", "");
    $("a[href='#" + this.element.id + "']").css("color", "red");
  }
}) as you showed me. but nothing happens? I also implements the scripts.

Comment: your sections are in **section** element not **p**, try change the **p** to **section[id]** in the javascript function

Comment: <script>

        $('section[id]').waypoint({
            handler: function (direction) {
                $("a").css("color", "");
                $("a[href='#" + this.element.id + "']").css("color", "red");
            }
        });

    </script>
It does not work no clue why.

Comment: Did you included the waypoint javascript into your page? Calling this ** $('section[id]')** on your page (I tested it) selects all your sections, so it should work. This is the list of all your section elements with id attribute set: section#about, section#clients, section#features, section#email-subscribe, section#contact. Check if you have links in your menu with corresponding href attributes

Comment: Yes i added   <script>
         $('section[id]').waypoint({
             handler: function (direction) {
                 $("a").css("color", "");
                 $("a[href='#" + this.element.id + "']").css("color", "red");
             }
         })
    </script>
 and it still does not work... I uploated it so you can see what i did.. You can see http://kaslabdesign.dk/TESTITEMPAGE.aspx where i tested it where it works but it does not work on my main page.. I am so sorry i am so slow ;P

Comment: On the test page it is working. On your main page you get error in console **TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function** which means that you are calling wainpoint script before it is initialized. Wrap the script like this **$(function(){ <YOUR SCRIPT> })**. I updated my answer so you can see what i mean.

Comment: I've done everything you say. You can see how the code is it's  uploated now, and it still dont work. You can see the script is like this  <script>
        $(function () {
            $('section[id]').waypoint({
                handler: function (direction) {
                    $("a").css("color", "");
                    $("a[href='#" + this.element.id + "']").css("color", "red");
                }
            })
        });
    </script>

Comment: I'm so sorry for this.

Comment: The waypoint script did not initialized correctly. There are some wrong script references in your page (especially for bootstrap), which may be the cause of this error, remove this invalid references.

Comment: I'm sorry about this, is there anyway that you could maybe help me more directly? like skype or anything.. I'm getting disperate and im sure you might think im dumb by now..

Comment: these are all invalid references in your page:assets/js/bootstrap.min.js, assets/js/bootstrap.min.js Try finding them in your source code, and remove them. If it is not so urgent I can connect with you next day

Comment: You linked "assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" twice "these are all invalid references in your page:assets/js/bootstrap.min.js,    assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" I removed it and nothing happend.

Comment: Uploated where i removed it

Comment: I think I know where is the problem. You include the jquery and waypoint script in the head element, but at the end of the page you include jquery again, and this include deletes the previous waypoint integration. So move your script from the head element to the body just after you call this script **<script>
                $('.carousel').carousel({
                    interval: 15000
                });
            </script>**